# Can someone explain the inclusion exclusion principle for me?

Tags: probability

[image]

This is the inclusion exclusion principle. Can someone explain this to me? Why does it end up being a summation and where do the -1 and the l term come from?

Comment: The best way to understand the inclusion-exclusion is by checking a Venn diagram for $n = 3$ and then the generalization should follow. This [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) wikipedia article.

Comment: Or to use indicator functions. But the lack of context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Venn diagram (for n=3) as suggested by a comment:

[image]

If one adds up $P(A)$, $P(B)$ and $P(C)$ then the grey and brown regions  will be considered twice, or, more precisely, the grey areas will be added twice and the brown region will be added three times.

To take care for the double addition, we may think the formula below to be true, but is it?

$$P(A\cup B\cup C)=^{\color{red}{???}}P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-(P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap C)+P(B\cup C)).$$

Now, we subtracted the brown region three times. That is , we did not take care of the brown region in the total. So we have to add it back again. Finally we get

$$P(A\cup B \cup C)=$$
$$P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-(P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap C)+P(B\cup C))+P(A\cap B\cap C).$$

This thread of thinking may be extended to 4 sets and any further.